# Difference in meaning between 'might be able' and can

Tags: meaning

Here's the text:

1)I’m not free this evening, but I might be able meet you tomorrow.

2)I’m not free this evening, but I can meet you tomorrow.

Is the meaning the same?

Comment: Using `might be able to` gives you some wiggle room. If the guy doesn't take a hint and calls you the next day too, you can go, "I said `might`"

Answer (score 1):

In **Sentence 1** you're saying you *may be able to* meet him, but *you are not certain* of this prospect. Therefore, you are not guaranteed to be able to meet tomorrow - but it's a possibility.

In **Sentence 2** you're saying you *can* meet him, meaning you're *certainly* available to meet if he'd like to. Therefore, you are guaranteeing your availability.